# How can I pass the parameters to controller correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, controller, action

1. From show view: I'd like to pass the shown message's id to discard action and trash the message.
2. From index view: I'd like to pass the checked messages' ids to discard action and trash them all at once.

But I only can trash one record at once even if I check multiple and submit from index view.
How can I archive both 1 and 2 with the same action????

Routes

```
  match 'messages/discard(/:id)' => 'messages#discard', :via => :post , :as => :discard_messages
```

index view

```
  <%= form_tag(:action => discard, :via => 'post') do %>   
   <% @messages.each do |m| %>
      <tr>
       <td><%= check_box_tag "id",m.id %></td>
       <td><%= m.last_message.id %></td>
       <td><%= 'unread' if m.is_unread?(current_user) %></td>
       <td><%= m.last_message.created_at.to_s(:jp) %></td>
       <td><%= m.last_sender.username %></td>
       <td><%= link_to m.subject, show_messages_path(:id => m, :breadcrumb => @box) %></td>
      </tr>
   <% end %>
   <%= submit_tag "discard", :class => 'btn' %>
  <% end %>
```

show view

```
<%= link_to 'Discard', discard_messages_path(@messages), :class => 'btn', :method => 'post'  %>
```

controller

```
  def discard  
      conversation = Conversation.find_all_by_id(params[:id])
    if conversation
      current_user.trash(conversation)
      flash[:notice] = "Message sent to trash."
    else
      conversations = Conversation.find(params[:conversations])
      conversations.each { |c| current_user.trash(c) }
      flash[:notice] = "Messages sent to trash."
    end
       redirect_to :back 
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the [] naming in your html, which rails will then make available as an array in the params

*index.html.erb*

```
<td><%= check_box_tag "message_id[]", m.id %></td>
```

*controller*

```
# ...
else
  conversations = Conversation.where("id IN (?)", params[:message_id][])
  # ...
```

to simplify things further I would remove the conditional in your action and create two separate actions

*routes*

```
resource :messages do 
  member do
    post 'discard' # /messages/:id/discard
  end
  collection do
    post 'discard_all' # /messages/discard_all?message_id[]=1&message_id[]=22
  end
end
```